# Standard/Conventions in Japanese

Tags: kanji, phrases, english-to-japanese

Looking up the words "standard" and "conventions" in Google Translate gives me multiple translations (as both words do have multiple meanings I pretty much expected that).

Using the following definitions of standard and convention, what kanji(s) are used:

Standard: something established by authority, custom, or general consent as a model or example

Convention: a way in which something is usually done, especially within a particular area or activity.

How would you say/write "coding standard" or "coding conventions"? (Am aware "coding" is just "コーディング". lol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary word for *standard* is 標準 and the primary word for *convention* is 慣習. But there are many possible expressions.

- コーディング標準: This refers to established, widely-known, authoritative and named standards. 標準 is a word that sounds highly technical. HTML Standard is HTML標準.
- コーディングスタンダード: The same as 標準. In the programming field it's often best to leave many words untranslated, you know :)
- コーディング規約: This can include more local ones like "Coding Style of XYZ Project/Company". Still this sounds you have to consider it a rule.
- コーディングスタイルガイド: Sounds less strict than 規約; it's not a rule but a guideline. How strictly you have to follow the guideline depends on the project.
- コーディングの慣習: Coding convention, which may even be undocumented.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanx! (I take it you work in tech too. lol)

Answer (score 0):

> Standard coding = 標準的記述法
>   Conventional coding = 慣例的記述法

e.g. regex is translated 正規表現